# Doctriine Query VS QueryBuilder Symfony 2.0

Tags: symfony, doctrine, query-builder

a have a bit of doubts with Doctrine Query and QueryBuilder.

I used to use simple Query in Repository such as:

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$dql = "select X from ApuestaBundle:Apuesta X  ORDER BY X.Jornada DESC";
$query = $em->createQuery($dql);
$entity = $query->getResult();
```

But I had to modify the function "createQuery($context = 'list')" from the Admin class of Sonata to filter the entities to show, and I had to use Query Builder like this:

```
public function createQuery($context = 'list'){
     $query = $this->getModelManager()->createQuery($this->getClass(), 'entity');

     $query->select ('e');
     $query->from($this->getClass(), 'e');
     $query->from('CoreBundle\Entity\Resource', 'r');
     $query->where('e.id = r.id AND r.company = :company');
     $query->setParameter('company', 1);  

     return $query;
}
```

So, here is my question, which is the differences of using Query or QueryBuilder. Because this way, I couldn't call a function of a Repository to change the function createQuery of the Admin Class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to answer your first question, the differences, in general Doctrine terms are as follows:

A **Query** is an object that represents a DQL query. The methods on it are mainly related to things like hydration and getting the results of the query: e.g. getResult(), getArrayResult(), getSQL()

A **QueryBuilder** is fluid way to build up a DQL query. The methods are mainly related to adding/changing the DQL clauses: e.g. select(), from(), where()

However, I'm not sure about the Sonata ProxyQueryInterface, which is returned from ModelManagerInterface::createQuery().